# How to get the Date, when particular field of a node is equal to some value?

Tags: 8, nodes, database

I have Content type called "**Items**", in that i have select list field for **status** referencing to Taxonomy terms(delivered,hold,dispatched etc.) .
 I want to store the date in some custom table when the item is "dispatched" and use that date in some other code.
 Which is function in which i can write logic to store date in table?  or any other way i can get dispatched date of the item?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the events described in [Entity CRUD, editing, and view hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_crud/8.3.x).

One example from the documentation:

```
function hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Update the entity's entry in a fictional table of this type of entity.
  db_update('example_entity')
    ->fields([
      'updated' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ])
    ->condition('id', $entity->id())
    ->execute();
}
```

You can get the original field values from `$entity->original->status` and check if the status has changed.